# Differential equations: temperature change calculate room temperature only given the temperatures of the object

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a Cup of tea with the inital temperature of $95^{\circ}\ {\rm C}$:

- After one hours the temperature is $47^{\circ}\ {\rm C}$ and after another hour it reaches $31^{\circ}\ {\rm C}$.
- The room temperature is constant $A$.
- How exactly do I calculate the room temperature with no other informations ?
- Is it even possible as our decreaste isn’t constant$\ldots$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hi there, this problem is direct application of Newton's Law of Cooling (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally people approximate Newton's Law of Cooling to as:
$\displaystyle \frac{T_{2} -T_{1}}{t} =k\left(\frac{T_{2} +T_{1}}{2} -T_{env}\right)$
So writing the two equations down: $(95-47)/1 = k(71-A) $ and $(47-31)/1=k(39-A)  $
So on solving the two equations we get $k = 1$ ,and $A = 23$

Comment: thanks alot. Where exactly did u find this formula ? Was confused about the question because my lecture only worked with the general formula e^(-kt)*(T0-Tenv ) +Tenv

Comment: This formula is an approximation from the differential form of the equation you told. T2-T1/t is nothing but dT/dt and T2+T1/2 is nothing but T.

Comment: If you do the actual calculations using the regular formula, you will get that this approximation will give the same answer as that when not approximated. However the value of $k=1.1$ and not $k=1$ `(https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ccvbtxax2e)`

Comment: Alright thank you. Figured out how to solve it with the general equation aswell and got the same answer .